# How do I integrate the bootstrap-modal plugin with AngularUI Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm in the process of migrating a jQuery based web application over to AngularJS.  I'm having trouble integrating the [bootstrap-modal plugin](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) with AngularUI Bootstrap.  The bootstrap-modal plugin offers a few features that I need: full-width modals, responsive design, and stackable modals.

I've made a basic attempt at integrating the two on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/stxyvVPYgzmlSNgUam3X?p=preview).  Note that the modal appears to be full-width when the window width is small.  But if you pop out the plunker preview window and increase the window width past ~979px, the modal drops down half the page.  I can see in the bootstrap-modal source code that the CSS sets the modal to "top: 50%" but then the JS is supposed to set a negative margin-top based on the modal height so the modal gets vertically aligned in the center of the page.  The JS isn't getting called properly so the modal is skewed towards the bottom of the page.

Code snippets from plunker below.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div modal="shouldBeOpen" close="close()" options="opts">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" ng-click="close('edit')" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
            <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-warning cancel" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Controller:**

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {

  $scope.open = function () {
    $scope.shouldBeOpen = true;
  };

  $scope.close = function () {
    $scope.closeMsg = 'I was closed at: ' + new Date();
    $scope.shouldBeOpen = false;
  };

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2'];

  $scope.opts = {
    backdropFade: true,
    dialogFade:true
  };

};
```

The alternative approach looks to be not using AngularUI Bootstrap and just code in the modal HTML using bootstrap's normal method.  I found this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/demettry/rYrFt/) that does exactly that while still using AngularJS.  I'd prefer to use the AngularUI method if possible.

Comment: For those reading this today, be warn that the **modal directive has been turned into a service** since [angular-ui 0.6](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes). This piece of code is now deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [ngEkathuwa modal service](https://github.com/sarath2/ngEkathuwa)

[angularjs twitter bootstrap modal not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111092/angularjs-twitter-bootstrap-modal-not-showing/18555370#18555370)

Comment: +1.  Your modal service looks promising.  Unfortunately, I'm not ready to switch over to bootstrap 3.0.  Is your modal service backwards compatible with bootstrap 2.x (i.e. 2.3.2)?

Comment: I eventually used this.  I forked it and added code to make the modal full height similar to what bootstrap-modal offers.  https://github.com/ravishivt/ngEkathuwa.  Thanks @sarath2!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your bootstrap-modal.css responsive section:  @media (max-width: 979px){...}, if you don't want it then modify it directly by changing from (max-width to min-width) or just copy that section of code and override it later in your html.

Comment: Thanks Noogen but modifying the CSS isn't really solving my problem.  The problem is that AngularUI Bootstrap framework isn't playing nice with the bootstrap-modal javascript code.  It doesn't appear to be calling it at all.  CSS modifications might fix some corner cases of the modal display but it won't fix the missing features that bootstrap-modal has to offer.

Comment: Yep, AngularUI example is very generic and specific to bootstrap so it might be hard to use the way you wanted.  Since you are using almost different or enhanced modal plugin, you can either write your own directive or find ways to enhance the AngularUI $dialog service.

Comment: +1, thanks Noogen.  I was hoping someone had already done it since it's a popular plugin but it looks like I'll have to get my hands dirty.